# HTML Form Resets on Submit

Tags: forms, security, submit, antivirus

I've a website used by over 500,000 people, but a tiny few (about 20) are reporting that one of the forms resets when clicking "submit".

I've stripped out other code, but the HTML in the FORM tags is complete:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<body>
<form id="fProfile" action="/cv.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row"><label for="fName">Your Name:</label><input type="text" id="fName" name="text" /></div>
    <div class="row"><label for="fEmail">Your Email:</label><input type="text" id="fEmail" name="email" /></div>
    <div class="row"><label for="fCvFile">Your CV:</label><input type="file" id="fCvFile" name="cv" /><em>Please only attach a CV, up to 200kb in size.</em></div>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="go" value="Save CV" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no JavaScript involved and the form could not be simpler!

Feedback is limited, but it's being reported that this happens on MSIE/Chrome/Firefox. It must be third party software interupting the form but reports come in from computers with McAfee/AVG/Avast. I can't find a single common factor other than the HTML ...

All reports say that the form resets on clicking the submit "Save CV" button without attempting to load a page but I'm unable to replicate this.

I've never come across anything like this and am hoping one of you have!

Thanks for any help or guidance.

EDIT: I've added a name/email input form too to show that it is just the *type=file* input that is resetting. The remainder of the form holds on to the entered text.

Comment: Hi, I'm still having this error reported.

It's defiantly resetting the form without attempting to upload it.

With no JavaScript in the form, I assume it must be AV software (what else is client side?) preventing the upload. The document uploaded is a CV (with the label/input labelled so) - could the AV detect this and prevent upload?

I've not heard of AV's preventing uploads but this could be part of HIPS/Data-Protection ... ?

Answer (score 0):

It says you are posting to a HTML page - surely you would need to post to a PhP page or similar.

So basically when you hit submit the page is just refreshing. Also in your HTML page you should always have a head tag.

Comment: The HTML is PHP generated via htaccess. The reports say that the page does not load/refresh/reload; it instantly resets/wipes the form.